# Securing WEB API Core when calling from MVC Core in Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, openid

Let's say I have two ASP.NET Core Web Projects. One Web API and one MVC.

- The user access the MVC web and the MVC web calls the API to get data.
- The user is authenticated in the MVC web through OpenId and Claims.
- The two webs are hosted in two different app services in Azure.

The Web API is called by the MVC App Service, not the user's client, right? So it won't be the user's Claim that should be used against the API, right?
And an app service does not run with a service account (or something like that), right? So we can't use the process user to authenticate against the API.
So how to secure the WEB Api to only let the MVC Web/App Service access the Web API/App Service?
And for development/testing purposes also from a local client?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to setup JWT Authentication between your MVC and API apps. Then add the same claims the users have from thier OpenId to the JWT token and send that to the API.